# How to detect a USB connection in linux/Qt

Tags: linux, qt, usb

i am extremely new to both qt and linux , can u please tell me a way how to detect a usb device connection and disconnection using qt in linux platform .

any help , doccuments, urls/sites where i can get the basic information (in detail would be even better) is appriciated.

please help

thanks in advance,

SAMBEET KUMAR

Comment: Please put tags that are relevant to your question - asp.net has no relevance to Linux, Qt or USB devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version available on your platform (most Linux platforms do), you can look into using DBus for notifications of things like that, and Qt has DBus support built-in via a [variety of classes](http://doc.trolltech.org/4.6/usingadaptors.html).

Answer (score 0):

since you are already working with Qt in a Linux environment, using KDE4 libraries should be easy to understand because they are built on top of Qt and follow similar design principles. With KDE4, you have access to the Solid library for managing system hardware information. This [tutorial](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Solid_Tutorials) can help you to get introduced.